# nodejs - How to force the user to complete profile after signup?

Tags: javascript, authentication, passport.js

How can i totally block user form access any route except the route for complete profile after user is already signup with min information.

complete profile means, user must add his/her job title and upload id copy and get verified by system admin, so he/she can login normal

best example could be upwork.com

i already config passport, may be i could block from jwt strategy

How could i achieve it and whats best practice?!

And I use express

```
// LOCAL STRATEGY
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
  usernameField: 'email'
}, async (email, password, done) => {
  try {
    // Find the user given the email
    const user = await User.findOne({ "local.email": email });

    // If not, handle it
    if (!user) {
      return done(null, false);
    }

    // Check if the password is correct
    const isMatch = await user.isValidPassword(password);

    // If not, handle it
    if (!isMatch) {
      return done(null, false);
    }

    // Otherwise, return the user
    done(null, user);
  } catch(error) {
    done(error, false);
  }
}));

// JSON WEB TOKENS STRATEGY
passport.use(new JwtStrategy({
  jwtFromRequest: cookieExtractor,
  secretOrKey: config.JWT_SECRET,
  passReqToCallback: true
}, async (req, payload, done) => {
  try {
    // Find the user specified in token
    const user = await User.findById(payload.sub);

    // If user doesn't exists, handle it
    if (!user) {
      return done(null, false);
    }

    // Otherwise, return the user
    req.user = user;
    done(null, user);
  } catch(error) {
    done(error, false);
  }
}));
```

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: I may be missing which server you're actually using. Could you add that information?

Comment: you mean server language?!
in this case nodejs

Comment: passport is just an authenticator, presumably you're also running a server, like hapi or express etc?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I use express, I will also add it to question

Comment: If you use express the answer is "write a middleware function".

Answer (score 0):

You basically need some kind of ACL based on user role.

Now you have 3 roles -> unregistered, almost-registered (without that job title) and fully-registered.

First solution - For every single route (or groups of routes) you have to specify what authorization you want to use. I think that easiest at this moment is to keep your passport implementation as it is and add simple middleware that will check if user has completed profile or not and based on that it deny/add access.

Second solution - You can also have two passport implementations, one for routes with complete profile (which checks also if user has title etc.) and one for the endpoint for the profile completition.

The last possibility - which I dont like as it is not solid solution and can have some issues in long run, but it will have minimal impact on your current solution is to check what the route is in the passport auth code and in case it is different to that "Complete Profile" endpoint, it will also check if your profile is completed.

If you plan to have more roles in your backend (i.e. some admins, leads of some groups etc.) then choose first or second solution or google more about ACL in node.js as you will need it anyway.
If you think there will be no more roles, the "last possibility" solution should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You're using express, so write a global middleware function that checks the authentication state and serves a 404 if the user's not authenticated:

```
// step 1: have a global error handler
// https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status);
  res.render('error', err);
});

// then, your global authentication middleware:
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (/* user authentication checks out */) {
    return next();
  }

  if (req.url === /* your single open route */) {
    return next();
  }

  // user is not authenticated: either we flag a global error, like this:
  next({ error: "user not authenticated", code: 403 });

  // or we redirect the user, because if there's only one route
  // they're allowed to access, just take them to that route.
  res.redirect('route/they/can/access');
});

// And then your actual route bindings go _after_ the above code.
```